# Given $p,q$ random primes, $p>q$ is $\large \left \lceil{\frac{p}q}\right \rceil $ on average prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

For example, wrote a C program below to iterate $100,000$ times to generate [random primes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) $p,q$ in the range $[2, 2147483647]$, recording the number of tries it took each result $\left \lceil \frac{p}q \right \rceil $ to be prime, then computing a final average for the number of tries.

On average, the number of $ceil$ tries was $1.32$

$\left \lfloor \left \lceil \frac{p}q \right \rceil  \right \rfloor = 1$

On average, the number of $floor$ tries was $2.99$

$\left \lceil \left \lfloor \frac{p}q \right \rfloor  \right \rceil = 3$

From a maths perspective, does this imply for random primes $p,q$, on average

$\large \left \lceil{\frac{p}q}\right \rceil $ is prime

and for random primes $p,q,r,s,t,u$, on average at least one of these

$\large \left \lfloor{\frac{p}q}\right \rfloor $ , $\large \left \lfloor{\frac{r}s}\right \rfloor $ , $\large \left \lfloor{\frac{t}u}\right \rfloor $ is prime

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <random>


int isPrimeNumberFast(uint64_t num)
{
    uint64_t i;

    if (num == 1) return 0;

    for (i = 2; i <= sqrt(num); i++)
    {
        if (num % i == 0)
        {
            // not prime
            return 0;
        }
    }

    // prime
    return 1;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv)
{
    uint64_t n, p, q, r, s, c;
    uint64_t iterations = 100000;

    std::random_device rd;     // only used once to initialise (seed) engine
    std::mt19937 rng(rd());    // random-number engine used (Mersenne-Twister in this case)
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> uni(2, 2147483647); // guaranteed unbiased

    s = 0;

    for (n = 1; n < iterations; n++)
    {
        c = 0;

        do
        {
            // As long as the input random numbers are uniformly 
            // distributed in the range, the primes chosen by this 
            // method will be uniformly distributed among the primes in that range, too.
            do { p = uni(rng); } while (isPrimeNumberFast(p) == 0);
            do { q = uni(rng); } while (isPrimeNumberFast(q) == 0);
            if (p > q) { r = ceil((float)p / q); } else { r = ceil((float)q / p); }
            s++; c++;
           printf("r=%lld c=%lld\n", r,c);
        } while (isPrimeNumberFast(r)==0);
           
        printf("n=%lld p=%lld q=%lld r=%lld s=%lld c=%lld\n",n, p,q,r,s,c);

    }

    printf("avg s=%0.2f\n", (float)s/ iterations);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If $p\le q$ then $\lceil p/q\rceil=1$, not a prime.

Comment: There is no such thing as "a random prime". You'll need to specify a probability distribution, or consider the limit as $N \to \infty$ of some property if primes less than $N$ are chosen with equal probability, etc.

Comment: @aschepler: Wouldn't the standard way to understand such statements  be to consider the uniform distribution on the finite set of pairs $(p,q)$ of primes below $N$, find the probability depending on $N$ and look at the limit as $N\to\infty$?

Comment: The limit is $\infty$ as $N\to \infty$ for both. This follows from the PNT or just $\pi(N)=O(\pi(N)-\pi(N/2))=o(N)$, looking at the expectancy of $p/q$ which is $\frac{(\sum_{p\le N} p)(\sum_{q\le N}1/q)}{\pi(N)^2} \ge \frac{\frac{N}2 (\pi(N)-\pi(N/2))}{\pi(N)^2}$.